# Lambda that copy object from one bucket to another in different accounts using AWS SDK copyobject method in javascript

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I would like to copy objects from the bucket in `account-1` to the other buckets in `account-2` using the `copyObject` method of the AWSJavaScriptSDK in a lambda. Right now it works by allowing the lambda role in `account-1` to write in the bucket in account `account-2` using the s3 bucket policies. The thing is that in the `account-2` we have a lot of buckets and we want to avoid adding permission to each of them every time that we create a lambda that writes or read in one of them.

I'm trying that the lambda in the `account-1` assume the role with the permissions to write and read in the `account-2` as follows.

1. In the `account-2` I have the role called `s3-account-2-full-access` with the `AmazonS3FullAccess` policy and the following trusted relationship:

   ```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
          "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::11111111111:role/lambda-account-1-role"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Condition": {}
      }
    ]
   }
   ```
2. In the `account-1` I have the `lambda-account-1-role` with the following policy attached.

   ```
       "Version": "2012-10-17",
       "Statement": [
           {
               "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
               "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::22222222222:role/s3-account-2-full-access"
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
3. In the lambda I'm assuming the role as follows:

```
const sts = new AWS.STS();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
    var sts_params = {
        RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::22222222222:role/s3-account-2-full-access',
        RoleSessionName: `id-${timestamp}`,
        DurationSeconds: 3600,
     };
    const { Credentials } =  await  sts.assumeRole(sts_params).promise();
    const { AccessKeyId, SecretAccessKey, SessionToken } = Credentials;

    const accessparams2 = {
      accessKeyId: AccessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: SecretAccessKey,
      sessionToken: SessionToken,
    };
    
    var s3 = new AWS.S3(accessparams2);
    var params = {
        Bucket: "account-2-bucket", 
        CopySource: "/account-1-bucket/file.txt", 
        Key: "file.txt"
    };
    const result = await s3.copyObject(params).promise();

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(result),
    };
    return response;
};
```

The thing here is that I'm getting the error `AccessDenied` during the `copyObject`. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but I can't figure out how I could copy the objects from account-1 to account-2 without having to edit the bucket policy in account-2.

Comment: could you share the error you get? Is it assuming the role or accessing to s3?

Comment: the error is accessing to S3. During the role assuming I have no error. `"errorType": "AccessDenied",`

Comment: I see that you are creating `accessparams2`. But where exactly is that used? It seems to me that you are still using your lambda role, not the assumed role when you create `var s3 = new AWS.S3();`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute S3 with the assume role permissions that you just get, I think that you are missing it :)

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3(accessparams2);
```

As bonus points:

- You are assuming role and instantiate the s3 object in every lambda execution, this is not necessary, you can do it out of your handler function to improve performance
- nodejs SDK use to have a `.promise()` method for every object so you probably can do something like the following to avoid the ugly Promise/callback thing in your `getCrossAccountCredentials` function (as you do with your s3 call): `const data = await sts.assumeRole(sts_params).promise();`

Comment: @RogerMP thanks for your help. I just added de `accessparams2` to the `var s3 = new AWS.S3();` and I'm still receiving the `AccessDenied` during the access to S3

Comment: It works with the `listObjects` method, I can read the bucket from the other account. But I can't use the `copyObject` method.

Comment: Hi, finally I got the solution. Moreover of your solution, one more thing is to add the desired permissions to the objects that you want to copy. For instance, in my case, I've made the object public and finally, I could manage to copy the object to the other account

Comment: @RogerMP Don't the temporary credentials that the assume role call yields have an expiration date? This means that if JosepB assumes role and creates S3 client just once at the top level of the module, there's the risk operation will fail if the temporary assume role credentials have expired. To avert that would require adding logic to check expiration of temp credentials and issue new ones (by doing another assume role call and creating a new S3 client with the new credentials) if the previous credentials have expired.

Comment: yep. If the session ends before the lambda shut downs you can just handle the forbidden exception and recreate the S3 object for the next session (according with the question conf)