# Saving file to /tmp in lambda from inside of a folder

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have a task of downloading and uploading files to s3 using lambda, the scenerio is like

- Download a file from s3 bucket1(request folder) to lambda
- Upload the same file to s3 bucket2(request folder) from lambda

Both the `downloadFiles` and `uploadFiles` fn are inside `utils/s3.js` inside the root directory(var/task/) in lambda

Here is my `utils/s3.js` downloadFiles fn

```
exports.downloadFiles = async () => {
  try{
    const location = path.join( __dirname , `../tmp/text.txt`);
    console.log(location); // prints /var/task/tmp/text.txt
    console.log(__dirname); // prints /var/task/utils
    const params = {
      Bucket: 'bucket1',
      Key: `request/text.txt`
    };

    const { Body } = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
    fs.writeFileSync(location, Body);
    return;
  }catch(e){
    throw new Error(e.message);
  }
};
```

Now there are two cases,

- If I create a folder in the root directory `tmp`, it gives this error

  *"EROFS: read-only file system, open '/var/task/tmp/text.txt'"*
- If I don't then

  *"ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/tmp/text.txt'"*

Now I have read most of the answeres on stackoverflow, I know I am supposed to save files to `/tmp/filename,` but how come I do the same and it doesn't work, where am I going so wrong?

Comment: I think that you have a bad approach here. 
Why use the temp folder? You can directly copy files with lambda without the need to download them to the temp folder (also temp folder have limit 500mb)
Example in Python (there is also some automation based on event trigger but you can see the logic): https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/aws-lambda-copy-object-among-s3-based-on-events/

Comment: What if I already have a sns trigger for this lambda function, on the basis of the sns I have to upload the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one commenter already stated, if you do not do anything with the file itself, it would be much better to just use the S3 API to copy the object instead of downloading and re-uploading it.

The relevant documentation can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#copyObject-property

Example:

```js
var params = {
  CopySource: "/<source-bucket>/<source-key>", 
  Bucket: "<destination-bucket>",
  Key: "<destination-key>"
};

s3.copyObject(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); 
   else     console.log(data);
});
```

Or if you want to use a promise, this should work as well:

```js
var params = {
  CopySource: "/<source-bucket>/<source-key>", 
  Bucket: "<destination-bucket>",
  Key: "<destination-key>"
};

try {
    const result = await s3.copyObject(params).promise();
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: how can I get the file url after copying it to the new bucket?

Comment: @Vinita There is no API for this as far as I know. But you can easily create the URL yourself. The format is: `https://<bucket>.s3.<region>.amazonaws.com/<object-key>`.

Comment: and I will have to make the destination bucket folders first manually or this can create dynamically like that in putObject()?

Comment: Ok it creates as well, @Jens Thank you so much for helping me out :)

Comment: One last doubt what changes would be needed if I had source and destination buckets in two different aws accounts

Comment: @Vinita Check this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62811782/lambda-that-copy-object-from-one-bucket-to-another-in-different-accounts-using-a